# YAML Deployment job environment and service connection from group variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to pass variable group to my yaml template with deployment job.
Is it possible to use one of the values from variable group as environment name and connection name in deployment job?

My case is a little complicated, sorry for that :D

```
variables:
  - group: ServiceVariables

pool: 'My Agent Pool'

extends:
  template: /releases/deployment.dev.yml
  parameters:
    variableGroups:
      - Gen2DEVVariables
      - PaymentService
```

deployment.dev.yml

```
parameters:
  - name: variableGroups
    type: object
    default: []

stages:
  - stage: Deployment
    variables:
      - ${{ each value in parameters.variableGroups }}:
        - group: ${{ value }}
    jobs:
      - template: /templates/jobs/deployToKubernetes.yml
        parameters:
          environmentName: $(azure_environment_name)
          dockerRegistryConnection: $(serviceConnection_dockerRegistry)
          kubernetesServiceConnection: $(serviceConnection_kubernetes)
          variableGroups: ${{ parameters.variableGroups }}
```

and deployToKubernetes.yml

```
parameters:
  - name: variableGroups
    type: object
    default: []
  - name: environmentName
    type: string
    values:
    - Develop
    - Test
    - UAT
    - Production
  - name: dockerRegistryConnection
  - name: kubernetesServiceConnection

jobs:
  - deployment: ${{ parameters.environmentName }}
    environment: ${{ parameters.environmentName }}
    variables:
    - ${{ each value in parameters.variableGroups }}:
      - group: ${{ value }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: none
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create Secret
            inputs:
              action: 'createSecret'
              kubernetesServiceConnection: ${{ parameters.kubernetesServiceConnection }}
              namespace: 'value'
              secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
              secretName: 'value'
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: ${{ parameters.dockerRegistryConnection }}
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: 'deploy'
              kubernetesServiceConnection: ${{ parameters.kubernetesServiceConnection }}
              namespace: 'value'
              manifests: 'value'
```

Comment: A couple of points here: 1) can you provide any console output from a run? does this compile and not work, or does it not compile? 2) from the edit page on a pipeline, after you've saved the pipeline, if you click the "..." menu and hit "Validate", what do you get? If it says "OK", hit that menu again and choose "Download full YAML" - you can then see what the template expands to.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole I've got the information, that the environment $(azure_environment_name) does not exists. 
When I delete allowed values of environmentName from deployToKubernetes.yml I've got another error - that job $(azure_environment_name) is invalid.

Comment: That didn't really answer what I asked for - you're not providing any output, screen shots of errors - all we have to go on is your interpretation of what's happening.

Comment: It seems like variables from variable group are 'resolved' after deployment parameters are set. Independent which syntax you choose: macro, template expression or runtime expression.

Errors are different between different syntaxes. 

By macro $(var_from_group) will be resolved to it's string representation (=ToString()).

By template expression ${{ variables.var_from_group }} it will be resolved to empty value.

By runtime expression $[variables.var_from_group] - pipeline could not be compiled with message: "Environment $[variables could not be found"